# Pivot date group selection and data source

Tags: pivot, powerpivot

I created a pivot on data from another tab. There is a start date filed which is in the format 2020-05-04 05:00:00, I don't how it happened but when I dragged the field into  "Rows" it showed up with the following:
start_date (Year)
start_date (Month)
start_date (Quarter)

I want to recreate this but not sure how it happen can some please help?

Also when I go to "change data source" no table is showing even thought the data in another tab in same workbook is there, where can I see the data source? I think I may have used Power Pivot and created data model but not sure how to update/refresh the data.